DevOps Best Practice - how to run Pull Request Tests in parallel
We currently run PR tests in isolation i.e. when someone creates a PR, the PR tests are run against their changes. Once the tests are successful, the code is merged into main branch.
This allows us to test code in isolation, but it means we have to queue PR's up one after the other until the tests complete.
We could add another PR agent and allow PR's to run in parallel, but that could lead to code not being tested together. i.e. if 2 or 3 PR tests are running at once, it would only be testing that PR's code changes and not code that could be merged in by the other PR's.
So, my question is what is best practice in this situation and how can we go about running tests in parallel to lessen the queue time waiting for testing?
My question explained in a little more detail:
I think my question relates more to testing microservices because our UIs, apis, grpc etc all have their own repos and are deployed separately as microservices.
Our PR tests run tests against things like logging in and being able to perform certain functions which tests all these microservices are working.
if i have parrallel PR tests running:

i could change code in microservice1 (in its own Azure repo) and run PR tests. All is ok.
i could change code in  microservice2 (in its own Azure repo) and run PR tests. All is ok.
They both get merged.

But, microservice1 changes alongside microservuce2 changes causes tests to fail. So code changes combined arent tested in PR stage and can cause failing code to be released.

This is an issue with how you approach testing. Can you make your tests independent and isolated? Can you use ephemeral environments? i.e. run the tests inside a container?

Hi @Paul, may I know if you also use Azure Repos as the remote Git provider? Does the answer by osim_ans work for you? That answer will cancel the PR validation build and then run a new build, if the source branch of the PR is updated, but the setting cannot cancel the build triggered by other PRs. You mentioned 2 or 3 PR tests, do you mean the 2nd or 3rd commits pushed the source branch of a single PR? Thanks for the clarification.

Hello @AlvinZhao-MSFT, we actually have this policy set already.
I have added more detail to my question....

Thanks for your update, but per your detail microservice1 changes alongside microservuce2 changes causes tests to fail and per my question, do you mean the 2nd or 3rd commits pushed the source branch of a single PR? Have you considered using 2 feature branches separately for the tests of your microservice1 & microservice2, so that you can create isolated PRs without bring the changes from the other microservice into your PR validation build?

I am also confused why the two services has their own repo but the changes will be brought to each other's PR validation build. Are you using repository resources to be consumed in one pipeline. Can you please share a sample of your pipeline definition and screenshots to help understand the issue your encountered? Thx.

Hello, yes they are isolated PRs.
A PR for microservice1 and a PR for Microservice2 is run in parrallel.
They both run the same set of PR tests. These tests pull a copy of main branch from every microservice in prod (other than the microservice being tested) and then test those code changes in PR validation tests.
If PRs are run in parrallel we dont test microservice1 and microservice2 together which may cause issues that werent detected when they were run in isolation.

OK. Based on the information you have shared so far, you have 2 repos for microservice1 and microservice2. You have at least 2 branches for each repo, so that you can create isolated PRs in each repo. For example, you created PR1 trying to merge the code of microservice1 from sourceBranch1 into targetBranch2 of repo1. At the same time, you created PR2 to merge the code of microservice2 from sourcebranch2 into targetBranch2 of repo2. Since the PRs were isolated, how came they could affect each other?

You added These tests pull a copy of main branch from every microservice in prod. This main branch belongs to the which repo, repo1, repo2 or a third repo? As suggested, can you please share a sample of your PR validation build definition to help understand how the two isolated PRs affected each other in your original post?

hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT,
in regards to your question "Since the PRs were isolated, how came they could affect each other?"
Yes, The PR's are isolated and will pass PR tests in their own right.
But once both PRs are merged into target branch (main) then the code combined could affect each other, since they are microservices.
Does that make sense? i.e. the changes in PR1 and the changes in PR2 are not tested together....(which could cause an issue)

Hi Paul, this is the part that was confusing us.  Let's say you have PR1 trying to merge the code of microservice1 from sourceBranch1 into the main  branch of repo1 and PR2 trying to merge the code of microservice2 from sourceBranch2 into the main branch of repo2. Since they were merging code into the two main branches of the two different repos, they should be isolated from each other, right? Then can you elaborate more why once both PRs are merged into each own target branch (main) then the code combined could affect each other?

By default, the PR validation build should only checkout the code from the sourcebranch of a PR. Is this your scenario? If yes, the code changes of PR2 should not be brought into the sourcebranch of the  PR1 or even the repo1, right? This was also why I requested you to share your build validation pipeline definition to confirm if the source code from another repo was checked out.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT,
By default, the PR validation build should only checkout the code from the sourcebranch of a PR. Is this your scenario? yes, that is my scenario.

We make a copy of Production onto a dev server and then deploy our application that has changed in sourcebranch.
pr tests run
So, the code for each pr is run in isolation

im suggesting PR1 and PR2 could affect each other once both deployed into main because they have not been tested together during the PR process...

I think we are close to the root cause. As far as I understand, what had caused the 2 PRs affected each other was the copy of Production onto a dev server then run tests and you were unable to guarantee the copy without using the code merged from another PR. For this, is it possible to use two separate dev servers and keep notes of the versions of source code from the two repos to create 2 different copies? For other possible options, please also update in your original post with the information from our discussions to engage the insights of the community experts.

Hey @AlvinZhao-MSFT, sorry just getting back to this and thank you for your responses so far.
Sorry, could you help me understand what you mean by this "For this, is it possible to use two separate dev servers and keep notes of the versions of source code from the two repos to create 2 different copies?"

As far as I understand the cause of the issue. Repo1 doesn't have the code of microservice2 and Repo2 doesn't have the code of microservice1; but they will be deployed to Production server, which will then be copied as a dev server for test. I was thinking if you could copy two dev servers with the expected versions of code to test with microservice1 and microservice2 respectively.


how can we go about running tests in parallel to lessen the queue time waiting for testing?

The simplest option would be to slice the test suite so that each slice can be run independently, if possible.
For example, instead of running a large suite of 1000 tests on a single pipeline job, you can use 4 jobs and run 250 tests in parallel on each job.

not sure i fully understand that because the 250 tests in parrallel would still mean that code changes aren't tested together

Paul no, that's not what I meant. If your tests are independent and can run isolated from each other you can split and run them in multiple jobs in the same pipeline. For example, run each category of tests in a separate job.

@Paul PS: just because you don't understand my answer - or it doesn't apply to your case - that's no reason to downvote. You ask a generic question without many details, and I gave you a generic answer. Also, if it doesn't help you it doesn't mean it won't help other members of SO.

i didnt intend to downvote, just to reply to your answer of which i am grateful for

To follow best practices, you need to update the branch policies of the target(main) branch and add the build validation check set to your PR build. Under the same settings, you also need to set the build expiration to "Immediately when main is updated".

When a PR build runs, it runs against the 'merge branch' (a merged version of your private and main branch). This above setting makes the PR build policy status fail whenever the main branch is updated, and requeues a new build and after that only it can allow the PR merge. This ensures that the PR-changes build successfully even if the main branch changes, ensuring that the build always runs with the latest changes(or tests) from the main branch.
Thus, in your case, you can safely run multiple PR builds in parallel as they will always contain the latest changes. For example, if you create two PRs, the last successful PR build from PR1 will contain the tests from the main branch and the PR1 branch. Let's say PR1 is merged. PR2 will now contain tests from the main branch (which now includes the changes from PR1) and the PR2 branch.
You may refer this MS doc for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation
